# Compare an ImageView's Background to a Drawable

Tags: android, imageview, compare

I have 16 blank square and i want to display a red Square randomly every 1 s so i used handler and this works.
But when the user clicks on this red square the score is up by 1.
i have tried to add onclicklistener to name but this is not what i need because once the squares background is red the score augments by 1 even when it returns to white so i have tried to add on click listener to each imageView starting with the first one but nothing happens; when i click on it the app crashes so what should i do?## Heading ##

the code:

```
Drawable RedSquare;

ImageView Image1;
TextView res;
Random random = new Random();
int score = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MediaPlayer mp  =MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.mp);
    mp.start();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reflex);
    RedSquare = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.redsquare);
    Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView Image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView Image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView Image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ImageView Image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    ImageView Image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    ImageView Image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    ImageView Image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    ImageView Image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    ImageView Image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
    ImageView Image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    ImageView Image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
    ImageView Image13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
    ImageView Image14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
    ImageView Image15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
    ImageView Image16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
    res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reflexresult);
    final ImageView[] Image = {Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4, Image5, Image6,
            Image7, Image8, Image9, Image10, Image11, Image12, Image13, Image14, Image15, Image16};


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GeneratePosition(Image);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    addScore();
}

public void GeneratePosition(ImageView[] Image) {

    int index = random.nextInt(Image.length);
    ImageView name = Image[index];
    for (ImageView imageView : Image) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.blanksquare));
    }

    name.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.redsquare));
}
public void addScore(){
    Image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(Image1.getBackground().equals(RedSquare)){
                score++;
                res.setText(score+"");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to compare the background? Just save the reference of the ImageView currently displaying the red background as field in the `GeneratePosition` method.

In the on click listener you get the reference of the view that was clicked. All you have to do is compare this to the reference you saved before.

Comment: you mean like this?
public void GeneratePosition(ImageView[] Image) { 

        int index = random.nextInt(Image.length);
        ImageView name = Image[index];
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

                score++;
                res.setText(score+"");
            }
        });
        for (ImageView imageView : Image) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.blanksquare));
        }

Comment: No, but this is also a possibility. But if you do so, you need to take care that your listener is removen in click or on timeout.

Comment: what is the second method?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work:
public void GeneratePosition(ImageView[] Image) {
int index = random.nextInt(Image.length); 
final ImageView name = Image[index];
name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("BUTTON", "clicked");
                score++;
    res.setText(score+""); }});
        for (ImageView imageView : Image) {
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.blanksquare));
name.setOnClickListener(null);}
 name.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.redsquare));

Comment: Of cause this is not working, because exactly after adding the OnClickListener to the chosen ImageView,  you are removing the OnClickListener of all your ImageViews.

Comment: where and how should i do this?
if i add it in the image.setOnClickListener(......){" here"}
this doesn't work corectly because the click listener won't turned off even if the redsquare position changed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation of how I would save this problem. It adds a listener to the view that should be clicked. If the user takes to long to click the highlighted ImageView it will highlight a new one. If the user clicks the highlighted ImageView in time the point get updated and the next ImageView is highlighted immediately.

```
private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 1000;
private static final int POINTS_PER_CORRECT_CLICK = 1;

private static final Handler HANDLER = new Handler();
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

private final Runnable startRoundOnTimeoutRunnable = new StartRoundOnTimeoutRunnable();
private final View.OnClickListener correctImageViewClickListener = new CorrectImageViewClickListener();

private final List<ImageView> availableImageViews;
private final TextView scoreDisplay;

private final Drawable blackSquare;
private final Drawable redSquare;

private int score = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // initialization of all views
    // and
    // assembling of  availableImageViews list

    startNewRound();
}

public void startNewRound() {
    resetAllImageViews();
    initializeNextImageViewToClick();
    startTimeout();
}

private void initializeNextImageViewToClick() {
    ImageView imageViewToClick = getRandomImageView();
    imageViewToClick.setBackground(redSquare);
    imageViewToClick.setOnClickListener(correctImageViewClickListener);
}

private void resetAllImageViews() {
    for (ImageView imageView : availableImageViews) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(blackSquare);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
}

private ImageView getRandomImageView() {
    int index = RANDOM.nextInt(availableImageViews.size());
    return availableImageViews.get(index);
}

private void incrementAndDisplayScore() {
    score += POINTS_PER_CORRECT_CLICK;
    scoreDisplay.setText("Score: " + score);
}

private void startTimeout() {
    HANDLER.postDelayed(startRoundOnTimeoutRunnable, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
}

private void cancelTimeout() {
    HANDLER.removeCallbacks(startRoundOnTimeoutRunnable);
}


private class CorrectImageViewClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cancelTimeout();
        incrementAndDisplayScore();
        startNewRound();
    }

}

private class StartRoundOnTimeoutRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startNewRound();
    }

}
```

Comment: how do i use the List<ImageView> availableImageViews